# Can anyone give me a simple explanation of how to implement this jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Okay, can someone please explain this to me like I'm 5?

I downloaded a zip file of this jQuery plugin (aSimpleTour) that is basically a popup tour/wizard through any website you load it onto. Only problem is...**I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SET IT UP!**

I'm fairly certain you need to call at least these to references in the head of your HTML?

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I understand that that references the entire jQuery library or something to that nature.

The tutorial of the popup tour has some code like this that I'm guessing goes in the `<body>` of your HTML page.

```
<script>
options = {
    data : [
      { element: '#id', 'tooltip' : 'This is a tooltip for some element #id' },
      { element: 'ul li:last a', 'tooltip' : 'The last link of some ul list' },
      { element: '.class', 'tooltip' : 'A tooltip for some class' }
    ],
    controlsPosition : 'RT'
  }

  $.aSimpleTour(options);
  </script>
```

So far I see what they're going for with the JSON syntax, not too sure about if function...

I have the files 3 files that came in the zip folder:

```
component.json
jquery.aSimpleTour.js
jquery.aSimpleTour.min.js
```

Okay, with all that in mind, where do I go from here? I'm a complete jQuery n00b and reading the docs didn't help much when implementing another's source code/app/what have you.

Can *anyone* help me out here or just give me a brief explanation of how to utilize a jQuery plugin?

Cheers!

Comment: Is this about jQuery, or the `aSimpleTour` plugin?

Comment: Whichever one you can help me out on?

Comment: @ClayBanks Here you will get solutions for your problem and its a unclear question. We can help you if you gives 1)what exactly is your problem ? 2) what you tried ?.

Comment: I'd highly recommend going through the [jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/) before going any further.

Comment: Did you even set the options according to what you are aiming at ?

Comment: I tried yes but failed miserably. What do I do with those 3 files? Do I put them in the same directory as my index.html?

Comment: You need to include jquery.aSimpleTour.min.js the same way you did with jquery-1.10.1.min.js. Not sure what you have to do with dat .json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 files you have include them in same way as you included the jquery ones(in head), but youll need to specify your path to files read this for more detail http://andreaslagerkvist.com/how-to-include-a-jquery-plug-in/.
The one issue here is that you are trying to init plugin before DOM is ready you should do this:

```
$(function () {
options = {
    data : [
      { element: '#id', 'tooltip' : 'This is a tooltip for some element #id' },
      { element: 'ul li:last a', 'tooltip' : 'The last link of some ul list' },
      { element: '.class', 'tooltip' : 'A tooltip for some class' }
    ],
    controlsPosition : 'RT'
  }

  $.aSimpleTour(options);
});
```

**EDIT:** You should also read [this](http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aSimpleTour/) as the plugin has a dependency to [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin which means you have to include that one too.

Answer (score -1):

jquery is a javascript library. You can either include it in your website directly or reference it hosted elsewhere (like a CDN or something), once referenced in your HTML file, you can then use the jquery syntax anywhere in your javascript.

In this case you want to use a jquery plugin, which means you need to have the library, and jquery plugin accessible from the users browser. And that would depend on how the plugin was written.

In this case, you've been given three files, I'd recommend putting the `.json` file in, and the `.min.` file in your website, and then you can reference both jquery and those files in your html.

Comment: I just want to set up the plugin so that it can cycle through certain elements in my web page and have the nifty popups guide the user through it